# Zone transfer Google Compute Engine internal DNS zone

Tags: google-compute-engine

In Google Compute Engine, each VM has it's own unique hostname: server-name.c.project-name.internal. While these names are static, the internal IPs are not.

From within the project, I can access the names, however, I'd like to access these also from my own network.

How do I do a zone transfer of my (c.)project-name.internal-Zone from Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this zone is internal to the network of your Google Cloud project, you can use the [Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn) to connect your external network to your Compute Engine network via an IPsec tunnel. This way, you will be able to access to this zone from your own network.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My questions was maybe not specific enough. I'd like to do a real zone transfer (AXFR)